# Lucene non indexed fields, case insensitive search?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Imagine that all documents have the following fields:

```
Field("Id", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
Field("From", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
Field("To", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
Field("Source", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
Field("Target", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
```

One of the requirements I have is to reuse the documents if **From**, **To** and **Source** are exactly the same (case insensitive).

However, they're not analyzed (e.g. with StandardAnalyzer which lowercases the terms before indexing).

1. Is it possible to do a case insensitive search to non analyzed
   fields?
2. What about `Field` name values, can I also do a case
   insensitive search to "From", "from", "FROM" ?

Overview:
I want to perform case insensitive search.

Example: "From:something", "from:Something", "FROM:SOMething", "from:SOMETHING" -> retrieve same result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - No.  You can always lowercase the fields yourself before indexing, or analyze them with an analyzer consisting of a [KeywordTokenizer](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_keyword_tokenizer.html) and [LowerCaseFilter](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d3/daa/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_lower_case_filter.html).  How you index in Lucene is very much a [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) operation.  If the way you analyze and index the fields doesn't enable your search needs, you'll have a rough time.

2 - Again, no (not that I'm aware of anyway).  You'dd need to handle this in your code.  If you just always use lowercase field names, it ought to be easy enough to normalize it though.

Comment: If I analyze all fields with the keywordTokenizer that weren't being analyzed before, will it consume a lot more space, considering that some of them might be of the size of 2 text paragraphs. The idea behind this is to be able to do fuzzy match and a exact match on the source field for ex. I'm having the same text in SourceExact field not analyzed and a SourceFuzzy field analyzed (StandardAnalyzer). That's why I want to perform case insensitive searches on the SourceExact field.

Comment: @pelican_george - No, shouldn't have an impact on space.  Analyzing a field with `KeywordAnalyzer` and leaving the field unanalyzed are virtually identical.  Adding the `LowerCaseFilter` could, theoretically, reduce the size of the index, but in practice with long fields, will likely have no impact on size at all.